# Not All Variables Are Being Passed To Second Page

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am capturing variables from a button press event in php.  If I echo the values to the current page they display as they should.  However, when the hyperlink is clicked only the first value is passed in the URL the others are blank.

What did I set-up incorrectly in my URL string so that the values did not all pass?

```
//Button click event
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $d1 = $_POST['firstlydate'];
    $d2 = $_POST['secondlydate'];
}


//sageworks has data as well as BlueGreen as the table displays exactly as it should
print "<td><a href='http://ils.com?gradata=".$d1."&eradata=".$d2."&billion=".$res->sageworks ."'</a>" . $res->BlueGreen  . "</td>";
```

Comment: Close your `<a>` tag properly.

Comment: @u_mulder - can you show me how I am not closing it properly?  NetBeans does not show an error

Comment: Have you checked the output of your "print" statement? Your <a> appears to be malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your data, the link will look like:

```
<a href='http://ils.com?gradata=some_data&eradata=some_data&billion=some_data'</a>
```

You miss a `>` before the `</a>`.

Comment: If I close it like this "'></a>" then the row is no longer a hyperlink?

Comment: The row, or the cell?

Comment: Sorry the entire column.  Data is returned, but no hyperlink.

Comment: It's because inside the `<a>`, you don't have anything. If you try with `<a href='...'>some text</a>`, you will see "some text" as a link in your cell.

Comment: Ah yes, that was it!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not closed properly, to avoid this type of error is recommended use:

```
print "<td><a href=\"http://ils.com?gradata=$d1&eradata=$d2&billion={$res->sageworks}\">{$res->BlueGreen}</a></td>";
```

Test:

```
$d1 = '1';
$d2 = '4';
$res = new \stdClass();
$res->sageworks = 'sageworks';
$res->BlueGreen = 'BlueGreen';

print "<td><a href=\"http://ils.com?gradata=$d1&eradata=$d2&billion={$res->sageworks}\">{$res->BlueGreen}</a></td>";
```

Html:

```
<td><a href="http://ils.com?gradata=1&eradata=4&billion=sageworks">BlueGreen</a></td>
```

Outpout:

[BlueGreen](http://ils.com?gradata=1&eradata=4&billion=sageworks)

Comment: Setting it up like this leaves the column blank with no data?

Comment: In the above example, I assume that `$res->BlueGreen` its the link content, it's correct?, it's true ensure has some value otherwise update the example to your needs

Comment: $res->BlueGreen is the field in the table that holds the data I want to display.  $res->sageworks is the anchor field, the id that I want to pass in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this. this may help

```
$url = "http://ils.com?gradata=$d1&eradata=$d2&billion=$res->sageworks";
```